# PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown interferes with click selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, listbox

I've implemented this code to perform a drag feature in a listBox.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/

But realized that the event PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown interferes with the clic selection. So when I would like to select an item, I have to do two click in the item.

What should I modify to fix that bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid interfering with normal selection, it is common to make the user drag an item a few pixels before you actually perform the drag&drop operation via DragDrop.DoDragDrop() (it is this call that interrupts normal click selection in your example).

One way to do this is to expand your example a little, and keep track of a "potential drag" by listening to the ListBox' PreviewMouseMove and PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp events, in addition to the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbOne" 
         PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
         PreviewMouseMove="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove"
         PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
         ... />
```

Notice how we use *potentialDragStartPoint* here, and how a lot of code is moved from ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown to ListBox_PreviewMouseMove:

```
ListBox dragSource = null;
Point? potentialDragStartPoint = null;

private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (potentialDragStartPoint == null)
    {
        ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;
        potentialDragStartPoint = e.GetPosition(parent);
    }
}

private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    potentialDragStartPoint = null;
}

private void ListBox_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (potentialDragStartPoint == null) { return; }

    ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;
    var dragPoint = e.GetPosition(parent);

    Vector potentialDragLength = dragPoint - potentialDragStartPoint.Value;
    if (potentialDragLength.Length > 5)
    {
        dragSource = parent;
        object data = GetDataFromListBox(dragSource, potentialDragStartPoint.Value);

        if (data != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(parent, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
            potentialDragStartPoint = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is great!! thank you so much for your solution!! It's perfect!!